# How to make a bar_polar chart with plotly, without frequency column?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

The first part of code is code from plotly website and it shows what i would like to make with my own data available.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

fig= px.bar_polar(df2, r="frequency", theta = "direction",
                 color = "strength", template = "plotly_dark",
                 color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()
```

Desired graph:
[image: What it should look like]

This is my code so far:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv (r"Lidar_final_corrected.csv")
print(df)
      wind_dir  Windspeed
0       227.35       2.12
1       233.41       1.65
2       227.75       1.52
3       217.75       1.71
4       204.64       2.21
...        ...        ...
3336    222.33      17.89
3337    221.52      17.21
3338    219.37      15.45
3339    217.23      16.09
3340    218.31      16.18

[3341 rows x 2 columns]

fig= px.bar_polar(df,theta = "wind_dir",
                 color = "wind_dir", template = "plotly_dark",
                 color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()
```

Current output:
[image: What it looks like]

Now if you look closely you can see that it is plotting something, but the colors are not right. I left out the frequency because I only have two columns to work with. Is there a workaround to make this plot work without the frequency?

(PS: the data is data based on time series so every 10min or 1 min a new entry is in there. I deleted the timestamp because I don't think I need it.)

Comment: Maybe the [windrose library](https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose) comes in handy here?

Comment: Thanks JohanC i made the windroses for now with windrose library wich is working just fine. But to have a little more interactivity and nicer visuals i would like to move to the plotly version mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a pandas groupby

```
grp = df.groupby(["wind_dir", "wind_speed"]).size().reset_index(name="frequency")
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001466/arrange-data-in-order-to-use-rose-diagram-with-plotly)

Then you can use the plotly code same as in the plotly docs!

```
fig = px.bar_polar(grp, r="frequency", theta="wind_dir",
    color="wind_speed", template="plotly_dark",
    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r
)
fig.show()
```

Happy plotting!
(for better results you should bin the wind directions and wind speeds.
(at least round them). Example of proper binning:
https://community.plotly.com/t/wind-rose-with-wind-speed-m-s-and-direction-deg-data-columns-need-help/33274/5