# Arrange data in order to use rose diagram with Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I tried to plot the wind rose diagram with Plotly. Here is the code I found from the web and it works perfectly.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.wind()
fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="frequency", theta="direction",
                   color="strength", template="plotly_dark",
                   color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()
```

Here is the output.[image]

But my data format is different from the required one. The required format is a **direction**(west,east-west, etc), **strength**(ex:level 1 to 6) and **frequency**(here I attached some part of the data frame).
[image]

But my dataset has around 80,000 data points for different time points. (I don't have frequency column and I have direction and strength for different time points).
How do I convert my data to make **frequency**
(here I attached some part of my data frame)
[image]

Comment: frequency calculation based on direction or strength?

Comment: thanks for the reply. In the required format, the data frame has only 128 rows(data frame length is 128). It comes from 16 different types of direction and 8 types of strength.(8*16=128). So all of the data points should fall within these 128 combinations (ex: wind from north and strength is 6+).i have no idea how to get this frequency like above required one.

Comment: So all the data points for different time values should fall within these 128 combinations.if some combination has more occurrences, the frequency for that combination should be high noh?

Comment: sounds like you need `size` from `groupby`. try `df.groupby(["direction"],["strength"]).size().reset_index(name="frequency")`

Comment: you could also do `df["direction"].value_counts(normalize=True)` if you only need one column condition to get relative frequency

Comment: @kevin Please add a sample of your original dataframe. Then the most likely thing is that liamsuma's comment should be the answer.

Comment: I'm adding the `pandas` tag as this is more a pandas problem than a plotly one.

Comment: @rpanai I added sample of my data frame

Comment: @liamsuma thanks, mate. Your suggestion worked perfectly for me

Comment: @kevin no prob, mate. cheers :)

Comment: @kevin if the answer was useful to you please consider to upvote it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your data like this:

[image]

```py
grp = df.groupby(["Direction","Strength"]).size()\
        .reset_index(name="frequency")
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your contribute but it seams that liamsuma already suggested how to do it on a comment. Using for loops on a dataframe is a bad practice especially when you could rather use a `groupby`.

Comment: True, I'll update the code @rpanai but still is different. In groupby , columns must be inside the same list, not different list per column.

Comment: This is better.

Comment: @dafmedinama Please consider sharing data samples as text and not images.